I'm not getting the full data sent to the server via axios
I want to send a student data to the backend server via axios.post, but im not getting the full object in my server route
Here's the 'student' object:
{
    "sisn": "202401",
    "level": "K1",
    "registration_date": "2024-11-01T05:56:27.705Z",
    "custodian": "Mother",
    "personal": {
        "firstname": "Jack",
        "middlename": "Sparrow",
        "lastname": "James",
        "lrn": "333333331111",
        "gender": "Male",
        "email": "sss@gmail.com",
        "birthdate": "2020-11-01",
        "height": "4'8\"",
        "blood_type": "B",
        "food_allergen": "None",
        "cell": "0915-881-5474",
        "weight": "43",
        "fortitude": "Normal",
        "siblings": 1,
        "photo_filename": "daniella.jpg",
        "photo": {}
    },
    "parents": {
        "mother": {
            "firstname": "Sssss",
            "middlename": "Sdfsdfsd",
            "lastname": "Assss",
            "address_line1": "Lot 1, Blk 2 Guyabano St., Brgy 178",
            "address_line2": "Camarin Caloocan City",
            "email": "nsdfdsf@gmail.com",
            "occupation": "housewife",
            "cell": "0945-555-5555",
            "marital_status": "Married",
            "photo_filename": "daniella.jpg",
            "photo": {}
        }
    }
}

The 'save' button OnClick handler
const AddStudent = async (e) =\> {
await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/students/add', student,
{ headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",}
}).then(result =\> {
SetIsStudentCreationShown(false)
SetIsStudentSummaryShown(true)
}).catch(error =\> {
console.log('something went wrong')
})
}

The route handler (some i deleted intentionally, im using multer )
    router.post('/add', (req,res,next) => {
      upload(req, res, async (err) => { 
       console.log(req.body)

      more code...
     }
   }

the console.log(req.body) shows some but now all the data in my object
    [Object: null prototype] {
      sisn: '202401',
      level: 'K1',
      registration_date: '2024-11-01T05:18:53.625Z',
      custodian: 'Mother',
      personal: [Object: null prototype] {
      firstname: 'Rowel',
      middlename: 'Gomez',
      lastname: 'Sss',
      lrn: '333333331111',
      gender: 'Male',
      email: 'sss@gmail.com',
      birthdate: '2020-11-01',
      height: `4'8"`,
      blood_type: 'B',
      food_allergen: 'None',
      cell: '0915-881-5474',
      weight: '43',
      fortitude: 'Normal',
      siblings: '1',
      photo_filename: 'daniella.jpg'
    }
  }

For some reason there is no parent field in the object. The weird thing is if I change the entry order of the field, parents first and then personal, the personal field in the object is nowhere to be found.
I need to have access to the whole student object inside my student route.
What should I do.
Here's the Onchange handler of my form that set the student State:
const HandleChangeFormInputs =(e) => {
e.stopPropagation();
let inputName = e.target.name; 
if (inputName.search('student')!==-1) {
    if (inputName.search('height')!==-1) { //5'9" or 5'10"
        var heightState, height;
        //allows empty value
        if (!e.target.value) heightState = e.target.value; 
        //removes all the formating
        height = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,''); 
        //allows values that has only feet number, no inches
        if (height.length === 1) heightState = height; 
        //accepts feet number and single digit inches  
        if (height.length === 2) heightState = `${height.slice(0,1)}'${height.slice(1,2)}"`;
        if (height.length === 3) heightState = `${height.slice(0,1)}'${height.slice(1,3)}"`;
        SetStudent({...student,personal:{...student.personal,height:heightState}}); 
    }
    // works for all input with mobile numbers 0915 881-5767    
    else if (inputName.search('cell') !==-1) { 
        let unmaskednumber, maskednumber; 
        //not really masked, since value is empty, only just for the code below
        if (!e.target.value) maskednumber = e.target.value; 
        else {
            //removes all the formating 
            unmaskednumber = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,''); 
            if (unmaskednumber.length <5) maskednumber = `${unmaskednumber.slice(0,e.target.value.length)}`; 
            else if (unmaskednumber.length < 8) maskednumber = `${unmaskednumber.slice(0,4)}-${unmaskednumber.slice(4,7)}`;
            else if (unmaskednumber.length < 12) maskednumber = `${unmaskednumber.slice(0,4)}-${unmaskednumber.slice(4,7)}-${unmaskednumber.slice(7,11)}`;
        }
        SetStudent({...student,personal:{...student.personal,cell:maskednumber}});
    }
    else {
        var name = inputName.slice(8);
        SetStudent({...student,personal:{...student.personal,[name]:e.target.value}});
    }
}
else if (inputName.search('mother')!==-1) {
    if (inputName.search('cell') !==-1) { 
        let unmaskednumber, maskednumber; 
        //not really masked, since value is empty, only just for the code below
        if (!e.target.value) maskednumber = e.target.value; 
        else {
            unmaskednumber = e.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/g,''); //removes all the formating
            if (unmaskednumber.length <5) maskednumber = `${unmaskednumber.slice(0,e.target.value.length)}`; 
            else if (unmaskednumber.length < 8) maskednumber = `${unmaskednumber.slice(0,4)}-${unmaskednumber.slice(4,7)}`;
            else if (unmaskednumber.length < 12) maskednumber = `${unmaskednumber.slice(0,4)}-${unmaskednumber.slice(4,7)}-${unmaskednumber.slice(7,11)}`;
        }
        SetStudent({...student,parents:{...student.parents,mother:{...student.parents.mother,cell:maskednumber}}});
    }
    else {
        var name = inputName.slice(7);
        SetStudent({...student,parents:{...student.parents,mother:{...student.parents.mother,[name]:e.target.value}}});
    }

}
else if (inputName.search('father')!==-1) {

}
else {
SetStudent({...student,[inputName]:e.target.value});
}

} //end of HandleChangeFormInputs

How are you adding your data to student? (and how are you logging it on the client to determine that it looks like the first value you shared?)

Its a state set by SetStudent everytime theres a change in my form inputs.  I console log it in the Add Student function, the student state is visible to that function.

Can you share that code please?

I have updated my post to include the  form inputs onChange handler. Thanks

Can you confirm the request model is defined with same keys in both frontend model and backend controller. Also note that parents at root is a collection of parent

I think model does not have anything to do with it because if you have noticed, in my code, i wanted to just console log it.

I can see all of the 'student' object contents when logging it in the browsers console before sending it via axios. But in the server's student route, some fields are missing (the parents field in particular).


Case 1:

If it is not a file upload, you just need to use json to send data instead of multipart/form-data :
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

By doing so, you will be able to get the full student object inside the:
console.log(req.body)

Because using melter middleware for nested objects could cause object's not being properly parsed.
Reference: nested objects in multer

Case 2:

However, If it's file upload, then you should go for the multer middleware as you have already configured.
If so, try implementing upload.fields() to handle nested objects.
Note that as the documentation says:
It should be array of objects
Reference: multer docs
You could also try the .any(), but as the documentation says it is not the best practice to use it from the perspective of security issues.
Hope this helps and solve your issue.

Oh well, that could be it. Thanks, Ill brush up on multer before changing my code. I will let everyone know.

Hey there, did you get it fixed though ?
